# Cannot perform web service invocation when lang="DE" returned by SOAP webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, axis, coldfusion-8

I have a ColdFusion application which consumes a SOAP webservice. When the following SOAP response is returned there is no error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header />
    <env:Body>
        <example-response xmlns="http://example.com/example">
            <example-asset lang="EN" />
        </example-response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However when the attrribute `lang` is changed to `DE` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header />
    <env:Body>
        <example-response xmlns="http://example.com/example">
            <example-asset lang="DE" />
        </example-response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot perform web service invocation example. 

The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is: AxisFault 
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException 
faultSubcode: 
faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in de.synyx.icsms.product_informations.ProductInformation - language-asset 
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: 
Invalid element in de.synyx.icsms.product_informations.ProductInformation - language-asset at 
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.onStartChild(BeanDeserializer.java:258) at 
org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035) at 
org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165) at 
org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141) at 
org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236) at 
org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384) at 
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2448) at org.apache.axis.cli... ''
```

Comment: If you call the web service via some mechanism other than ColdFusion, what do you get? The error looks to me like the internal workings of the web service isn't liking something it's having to process. It's difficult to say much without seeing the code that's erroring.